# Q: [iOS] Can I send push notifications to both debug and Ad Hoc builds at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Through Salesforce I can send a push and receive it on debug build built through Xcode if I use a dev APNS cert, I can receive it on an Ad Hoc build if I use a prod (Apple Push Services) APNS cert, but I can't seem to do both at the same time. When creating an Apple Push Services prod cert it says it can be used for both sandbox and production, so I was hoping I could send to both debug and ad hoc builds at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

When sending a push there are three things involved which need to be in alignment.

You either have a dev push cert in combination with a debug build and the push is sent over the Apple sandbox dev environment.

OR

You have a prod push cert in combination with a release build and the push is sent over the Apple prod environment.

OR you don't use certs but use push keys, which can be sent over both environments.

But the Apple environment needs to match to if the app is a prod or dev build as the push token the app gets is different.

You cannot mix and match any of these up otherwise the push will not be delivered to the app.

The only way to send a push to a debug and release build simultaneously would for your server to send the push twice - once using the prod cert over the apple prod network and once using the dev cert over the apple sandbox network. One of these two pushes will fail and the other one will succeed.

Or when your app contacts your server and sends it the push token, it also indicates if that token is for a release build or a debug build of the app, and then the server sends the push using the appropriate cert and apple network.

("When creating an Apple Push Services prod cert it says it can be used for both sandbox and production" Thats not the case in my experience, unless this is a new feature. Anyway as mentioned, the Apple environment and app build still need to align).

Comment: I've found that if you create the certificate correctly for both Sandbox & Production you can use it for both.   When creating the certificate, from [your developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/distribution/create), make sure to select:

> Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)